# I can't use math methods in Java

Tags: java, android, math

I need to use "hypot" method in my Android game however eclipse says there is no such a method. Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;//in the top of my file
float distance = hypot(xdif, ydif);//somewhere in the code
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to import types in `java.lang` at all. There's an implicit `import java.lang.*;` already. But importing a type *just* makes that type available by its simple name; it doesn't mean you can refer to the methods without specifying the type. You have three options:

- Use a static import for each function you want:

  ```
  import static java.lang.Math.hypot;
  // etc
  ```
- Use a wildcard static import:

  ```
  import static java.lang.Math.*;
  ```
- Explicitly refer to the static method:

  ```
  // See note below
  float distance = Math.hypot(xdif, ydif);
  ```

Also note that `hypot` returns `double`, not `float` - so you either need to cast, or make `distance` a `double`:

```
// Either this...
double distance = hypot(xdif, ydif);

// Or this...
float distance = (float) hypot(xdif, ydif);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double distance = Math.hypot(xdif, ydif);
```

or

```
import static java.lang.Math.hypot;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use static methods without the class they are in, you have to import it statically. Change your code to either this:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
float distance = hypot(xdif, ydif);//somewhere in the code
```

or this:

```
import java.lang.Math;
float distance = Math.hypot(xdif, ydif);//somewhere in the code
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First of all java.lang.* is already included, So u do NOT need to import it.

**2.** To access a method in Math class you can do the following...

**-** Access the **static method using Class name and dot operator.**

`Math.abs(-10);`

**-** Access the **static method directly, then u need to import as below.**

`import static java.lang.Math.abs;`

`abs(-10);`